# Angular 2 Router uncaught promise

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [  
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'projects', loadChildren: 'app/projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule' },
    { path: 'hello', loadChildren: 'app/my-project/my-project.module#MyProjectModule' }
];
```

Only contact path loads but the one with loadChildren gives following error:

```
error_handler.js:50 
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined at NoProviderError.set [as stack]
```

I am following the official docs but no luck, changing to absolute paths works, but then i have to import root component of each feature module say have to import ProjectsComponent which is root for ProjectsModule.

Augury routes are as follows and that is what i wanted::
[image: Augury routes]

Whats Wrong!!

Comment: This stack error happens when it's not compiling with lazy loading. Nevertheless, your log tells `at NoProviderError.set [as stack]` so you should check your `modules` and see if you didn't forget any.

Comment: I checked with https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/ngmodule/ts/eplnkr.html on my localmachine, it works. Is there a problem with angular CLI

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but I was also getting the error "Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined" when running unit tests with Karma. I was able to fix it by upgrading zone.js to 0.7.4: `npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4`

Comment: @Jim thanks buddy! it worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this.. 
[Angular issue 13941](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13941)

Answer (score 0):

*I am adding the answer myself at posted by Jim comment for clarity*

I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but I was also getting the error "Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined" when running unit tests with Karma.I was able to fix it by upgrading zone.js to 0.7.4:

**npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4** – Jim 1 hour ago